# Generate Google Charts images using CRON and add to PDF

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, google-visualization, cron-task

> I want to be able to generate a Google Charts images and this will
>   done by cron job.

To start with, I understand that Google Charts is a client-side library that runs in browsers, so you can only generate charts in the browser. And also, I'm using a PHP Framework.

Here's where I am right now:

1. Firstly, I finished creating the PDF. Using MPDF, I was able to
   successfully make a daily report in PDF format via cron.
2. Secondly, I already have generated server-side Google charts as images  **via the browser**, and save those images to a folder. I was able to insert the image of the graph I wanted to
   add.
   https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing

**But what I want is the cron job to generated the chart image. Setting the CRON, I'd like to generate an image of the certain Google Chart.**

This is the closest topic I can find that is related to my question, but this thread didn't have an answer: [Using Google Charts API Generated Graphic in FPDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31380440/using-google-charts-api-generated-graphic-in-fpdf)

Comment: seen this topic a few times, check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38846683/5090771), also try searching for answers to _email_ google chart, similar process...

Comment: I actually end up just using the deprecated Google Image Charts.

Comment: I want to do the same.